# Interpretability of Impulse Response Functiona and Granger Causality test

Tags: r, time-series, granger-causality, impulse-response

I have two monthly time series:

```
Uncertainty =  [1] 0.01533956 0.01500000 0.01515492 0.01660436 0.01539195 0.01530921 0.01500000 0.01507573 0.01537311 0.01506824
 [11] 0.01500000 0.01508481 0.01507803 0.01513853 0.01515810 0.01500000 0.01507083 0.01514608 0.01507513 0.01521903
 [21] 0.01553050 0.01524808 0.01561406 0.01540157 0.01560901 0.01528062 0.01538875 0.01693837 0.01563371 0.01507710
 [31] 0.01507668 0.01548777 0.01550305 0.01500000 0.01543159 0.01522438 0.01521681 0.01529893 0.01546539 0.01534459
 [41] 0.01600013 0.01550186 0.01535940 0.01506606 0.01558089 0.01561439 0.01538742 0.01539314 0.01572966 0.01522952
 [51] 0.01527997 0.01509207 0.01506982 0.01547658 0.01512625 0.01513057 0.01533402 0.01519202 0.01513993 0.01521939
 [61] 0.01539575 0.01520839 0.01588535 0.01572713 0.01615311 0.01513049 0.01526481 0.01512937 0.01536617 0.01532413
 [71] 0.01513198 0.01527031 0.01529635 0.01507639 0.01548765 0.01555386 0.01590075 0.01508926 0.01500000 0.01525956
 [81] 0.01545155 0.01568805 0.01644544 0.01567878 0.01713529 0.01543550 0.01580116 0.01546357 0.01570979 0.01731016
 [91] 0.01558545 0.01513909 0.01610364 0.01589215 0.01592734 0.01607330 0.01677083 0.01577067 0.01603103 0.01585123
[101] 0.01694318 0.01635578 0.01593732 0.01637276 0.01658348 0.01588470 0.01731524 0.01625313 0.01725210 0.01887750
[111] 0.01831379 0.01803439 0.01725425 0.01705499 0.01617290 0.01982561 0.02326231 0.01584796 0.01573880 0.01543948
[121] 0.01561067 0.01507204 0.01574988 0.01659510 0.01665554 0.01597964 0.01541206 0.01553702 0.01609477 0.01564662
[131] 0.01542659 0.01549741
```

and Annual change in House Prices (in natural logs)

```
House Prices =  [1]  0.060761055  0.069950884  0.092563502  0.096516298  0.081337114  0.083240450  0.054460548  0.080128787
  [9]  0.068890937  0.083673567  0.064829087  0.041281629  0.061894862  0.091175931  0.080636150  0.087343516
 [17]  0.111036660  0.108404162  0.257142914  0.102603577  0.116511896  0.114216916  0.127491093  0.137534698
 [25]  0.129671913  0.111374618  0.108207369  0.131192210  0.132858904  0.131548705  0.000000000  0.114723242
 [33]  0.111291747  0.112244978  0.102148870  0.092714275  0.054940020  0.085817967  0.074571996  0.055771684
 [41]  0.042966671  0.044293063  0.032258984 -0.013020362 -0.030328532 -0.027837669 -0.035178644 -0.030125696
 [49] -0.054178897 -0.058369321 -0.086977111 -0.082298625 -0.055672332 -0.070839196 -0.063850213 -0.025592358
 [57] -0.004794181  0.003381210  0.024675240  0.011343808  0.042312953  0.059378202  0.056705519  0.076140995
 [65]  0.039093124  0.040937556  0.048601014  0.083007151  0.033627306  0.021100200  0.008240520  0.021195008
 [73]  0.005731057 -0.019777949 -0.013459304 -0.000481840  0.019458685 -0.006134143  0.014640055 -0.018973359
 [81] -0.000635282  0.001130525  0.010367129 -0.031045975 -0.000818617  0.016362232  0.028955592 -0.010045934
 [89] -0.015040926  0.022725145 -0.020442085 -0.037055871 -0.013855981 -0.030070854 -0.042353414  0.023625106
 [97] -0.007840661 -0.001485553 -0.001935076 -0.007745723  0.009077794 -0.012910669  0.013267345  0.020921684
[105]  0.012565305  0.025839041  0.057484514  0.011076450  0.033411114  0.041928308  0.027035973  0.046183315
[113]  0.054138355  0.068260861  0.032538699  0.050712983  0.072123289  0.033179492  0.018661604  0.051411799
[121]  0.073918352  0.070047567  0.200971642  0.143036668 -0.031191576 -0.014253957 -0.003606198  0.012085764
[129] -0.021088330  0.017174875  0.020631125  0.007208228
```

In a simple model (using only these two variables), I want to study if uncertainty has an effect on House Prices (expressed in annual change on the natural logarithm of house prices). In an attempt to study this relationship I conduct a simple VAR model using 13 lags as indicated by the BIC test:

```
library(vars)
VARSample <- cbind(House Prices, Uncertainty)
c(House Prices)
var.2c <- VAR(VARSample, p = 13, type = "const")
plot(irf(var.2c, impulse = "Uncertainty", response = "House Prices", boot = T))
```

With the following graph as a result:

[image: Impulse Response Function of the reaction of House Prices to a shock in uncertainty]
Which seems not to be significant. Moreover, I conduct a Granger causality test as follows:

```
lmtest::grangertest(Uncertainty,House Prices,13) 
lmtest::grangertest(House Prices,Uncertainty,13)
```

where I get the following:

```
Model 1: House Prices ~ Lags(House Prices, 1:13) + Lags(Uncertainty, 1:13)
Model 2: House Prices ~ Lags(House Prices, 1:13)
  Res.Df  Df     F    Pr(>F)    
1     92                        
2    105 -13 3.389 0.0002828 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

and,

```
Model 1: Uncertainty ~ Lags(Uncertainty, 1:13) + Lags(House Prices, 1:13)
Model 2: Uncertainty ~ Lags(Uncertainty, 1:13)
  Res.Df  Df      F Pr(>F)
1     92                  
2    105 -13 0.7937  0.665
```

From these two results, can I conclude that there is an effect of uncertainty on House prices?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the Granger causality test and the impulse-response (IRF) graph suggest that uncertainty is having an effect on house prices. Loose translation of these two:

- Granger test: knowing historical uncertainty extra to historical house prices helps explain current house prices better.
- IRF: increased uncertainty is followed by increased house prices 8 periods ahead (with 95% confidence). The effects in other periods cannot be distinguished from zero at 95% confidence level.